# Yii2 console script not working

Tags: console, yii2

I want to automatically download my database backup weekly. I'm using xampp on windows. I've google around and found that I've to make use of windows task scheduler and the action script in my console controller. I've read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2/) and [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10345) and tried running the command from command prompt. I'm getting 'Unknown command'.

My code in console controller for now just for testing

```
<?php
namespace console\controllers;


use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

/**
 * Cron controller
 */
class TestController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        echo "cron service runnning";
  }

}
```

And my `main` config file

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
         'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    ],
    ],

    'modules' => [
    'rbac' =>  [
        'class' => 'johnitvn\rbacplus\Module'
    ]       
],

    'params' => $params,
];
```

The error I'm getting
[image]

Comment: try command `yii`. What message is returned?

Comment: I'm getting the available yii command list

Comment: i'm getting the same error. did you find a solution to your problem @gojiraki ?

Comment: Can you add the location of your "main.php"? Is it under "console\config"?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `TestController.php` file in `console/controllers` folder and its name is written correctly.

Then from project root folder you can call your command like that:

```
php yii test/index
```

or just:

```
php yii test
```

(because `index` is a default action (configured in `$defaultAction`) and you can omit it).

If you are outside of project folder, make sure to provide correct path:

```
php /path/to/project/folder/yii test
```

Comment: Yeah! my file is in the `console/controllers` and I've already did what you have said but still not able to run the command from command prompt. Still getting `unknown command`

Comment: @gojiraki Please show how exactly you call it (full command) and full error message in this case.

Comment: Hi! I've edited my question and added the screenshot.